# Custom components are not known elements in Angular CLI app

Tags: javascript, angular, components, angular-cli

I am looking at learning Angular 8 with the Angular CLI.

I have added two new components to a core module which i have then imported to the app module.

When I try to render the components in my app html the 'not known element' error is thrown in the console.

I am unsure as to why?

Here is my `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { CoreModule } from "./core/core.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, NoopAnimationsModule, CoreModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My `core.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { InputComponent } from "../input/input.component";
import { GraphComponent } from "../graph/graph.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [InputComponent, GraphComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [InputComponent, GraphComponent]
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

`app.component.html`

```
<div>
  <InputComponent></InputComponent>
  <GraphComponent></GraphComponent>
</div>
```

And an example of one of the custom components:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss']
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: your code looks correct. Could you rerun `ng serve`?

Answer (score 5):

I just realised that I am not referring to the components with the correct selectors!

I should be using: `app-input` & `app-graph` in the `app.component.html`.